# SQL Average of values only if different from 0

Tags: sql, ms-access, average, group

I have a table in Access which is an ODBC connexion and from which I query my data via VBA doing an average in certain fields only with the values that are not equal to 0 while in other fields I don’t need to clean values. Values in TABLE1 are every 5 seconds of double as data type
and I want to have an average every minute or hour.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(
timestamp,
FilteredAverage1,
Average2)

SELECT 
Cdate(format( TABLE1.timestamp ,’dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:00)),
AVG(iif(TABLE1.Column1 = 0, null, TABLE1.Column1)),
AVG(TABLE1.Column2)

FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY Cdate(format( TABLE1.timestamp ,’dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:00))
```

The query kinda works but my main concern is that it not only removes values that are equal to 0 prior doing the average but if for exemple I have a value like 7,7802863 it converts that value removing the 0 in the decimal using 7,782863 intead. How come it does that?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _it converts that value removing the 0 in the decimal using 7,782863 intead_ ... there is no way the query can do that. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that you could try to filter your set of data using a SQL WHERE instead the VB function Iif

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(
timestamp,
FilteredAverage1,
Average2)
SELECT 
Cdate(format( TABLE1.timestamp ,’dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:00)),
AVG(TABLE1.Column1),
AVG(TABLE1.Column2)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.Column1 <> 0 
GROUP BY Cdate(format( TABLE1.timestamp ,’dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:00))
```